# Problem on Laravel 5 Delete Button in foreach?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using the Laravel form.

For now I've successfully created a CRUD for an offers in my project, but one thing bothers me:

How can I set a Delete button in my list of image, instead of the specific edit page?

So, here's my code:

Included :

`use App\ImageTracking;
use App\Image;
use DB;`

table offers :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('offers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('idOffers')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('id_spons')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('id_spons')->references('id_sponsors')->on('sponsors')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->string('Name_offre');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('subject');
        $table->string('froms');
        $table->string('TrackingURL');
        $table->string('subId');
        $table->string('unSub');

        //->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

table image :

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('image', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id_imageUnsb');
        $table->integer('offers_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('offers_id')->references('idOffers')->on('offers')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->string('imageUnsb');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

---

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($offers->Images as $image)
    <tr>
        <td><img src="{{ url('storage/photo/'.$image->imageUnsb) }}" width="100px" height="100px"></td>
        <td>
            <form action=" {{ url('/offers/'.$image->idOffers) }}" method="post">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                <button type="submit" class="deleteConfirmation btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

and that my controller :

```
public function destroyImageUnsb(Request $request, $id)
{
    $image = Image::where('offers_id', $id)->first()->delete();
    return redirect('editOffers');
}
```

Route :

```
Route::delete('/offers/{idOffers}','OffersController@destroyImageUnsb');
```

Comment: you shouldn't put a form inside a foreach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try this:

**Route**

```
Route::get('/offers/{idOffers}','OffersController@destroyImageUnsb')->name('offers');
```

**Your View**

```
@foreach($offers->Images as $image)
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="{{ url('storage/photo/'.$image->imageUnsb) }}" width="100px" height="100px"></td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="{{ route('offers', [$image->offers_id]) }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
```

**Your Controller function**

```
use Redirect;


     public function destroyImageUnsb($id)
        {
            $image = Image::where('offers_id', $id)->delete();
            return Redirect::to('editOffers/'.$id);
        }
```

Please updated your `editoffers` route like:

```
Route::get('/editOffers/{id}','OffersController@edit');
```

**Updated Answer**

**Your View**

```
@foreach($offers->Images as $image)
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="{{ url('storage/photo/'.$image->imageUnsb) }}" width="100px" height="100px"></td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="{{ route('offers', [$image->id_imageUnsb]) }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
```

**Your Controller function**

```
 use Redirect;


         public function destroyImageUnsb($id)
            {
                $offerId = Image::where('id_imageUnsb',$id)->first();
                $offerId = $offerId->offers_id;
                $image = Image::where('id_imageUnsb', $id)->delete();
                return Redirect::to('editOffers/'.$offerId);
            }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186475/discussion-on-answer-by-saurabh-dhariwal-problem-on-laravel-5-delete-button-in-f).

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to **`laravel`**  or if your **`project is small`**  **SKIP THIS ANSWER**

Open your model it may be `Offer`  and paste the following code into it

```
/**
* @function     tableActionButtons
* @author       Manojkiran <manojkiran10031998@gmail.com>
* @param        string  $fullUrl
* @param        integer  $id
* @param        string  $titleValue
* @param        array  $buttonActions
* @usage        Generates the buttons
* @version      1.0
**/
/*
NOTE:

if you want to show tooltip you need the JQUERY JS and tooltip Javascript

if you are not well in JavaScript Just Use My Function toolTipScript()



|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Generates the buttons
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Generates the buttons while displaying the table data in laravel
|when the project is bigger and if you are laravel expert you this.
|But if you are the learner just go with basic
|
|Basically It Will generate the buttons for show edit delete record with the default
|Route::resource('foo',FooController);
|
|//requirements
|
|//bootstrap --version (4.1.3)
|//  <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="" crossorigin="">
|//fontawesome --version (5.6.0(all))
|//<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.0/css/all.css" integrity="" crossorigin="">
|
|if you want to show tooltip you nee the jquery and tooltip you need these js and toottipscript javascript or use my function toolTipScript
|
|//jquery
|// <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
|//popper js
|// <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
|//bootstrap js
|// <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
|
|usage
|option1:
|tableActionButtons(url()->full(),$item->id,$item->name);
|this will generate all the buttons
|
|option2:
|tableActionButtons(url()->full(),$item->id,$item->name,['edit',delete]);
|this will generate edit and delete the buttons
|
|option3:
|tableActionButtons(url()->full(),$item->id,$item->name,['edit',delete,delete],'group');
|this will generate all the buttons with button grouping
|
|option4:
|tableActionButtons(url()->full(),$item->id,$item->name,['show','edit','delete'],'dropdown');
|this will generate all the buttons with button dropdown
|
*/

public static  function tableActionButtons($fullUrl,$id,$titleValue,$buttonActions = ['show', 'edit', 'delete'],$buttonOptions='')
{


        //Value of the post Method
        $postMethod = 'POST';
        //if the application is laravel then csrf is used

        $token = csrf_token();

        //NON laravel application
        // if (function_exists('csrf_token'))
        // {
        //   $token = csrf_token();
        // }elseif (!function_exists('csrf_token'))
        // //else if the mcrypt id is used if the function exits
        //     {
        //         if (function_exists('mcrypt_create_iv'))
        //         {
        //             // if the mcrypt_create_iv id is used if the function exits the set the token
        //             $token = bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(32, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
        //         }
        //         else{
        //             // elseopenssl_random_pseudo_bytes is used if the function exits the set the token
        //             $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
        //         }
        //     }

        //action button Value
        //(url()->full()) will pass the current browser url to the function[only aplicable in laravel]
        $urlWithId  =$fullUrl.'/'.$id;
        //Charset UsedByFrom
        $charset = 'UTF-8';

        // Start Delete Button Arguments
        //title for delete functions
        $deleteFunctionTitle = 'Delete';
        //class name for the deletebutton
        $deleteButtonClass = 'btn-delete btn btn-xs btn-danger';
        //Icon for the delete Button
        $deleteButtonIcon = 'fa fa-trash';
        //text for the delete button
        $deleteButtonText  = '';
        //dialog Which needs to be displayes while deleting the record
        $deleteConfirmationDialog = 'Are You Sure you wnat to delete ' . $titleValue;

        $deleteButtonTooltopPostion = 'top';
        // End Delete Button Arguments


         // Start Edit Button Arguments
        //title for Edit functions
        $editFunctionTitle = 'Edit';
        $editButtonClass = 'btn-delete btn btn-xs btn-primary';
        //Icon for the Edit Button
        $editButtonIcon = 'fa fa-edit';
        //text for the Edit button
        $editButtonText  = '';
        $editButtonTooltopPostion = 'top';
        // End Edit Button Arguments


        // Start Show Button Arguments
        //title for Edit functions
        $showFunctionTitle = 'Show';
        $showButtonClass = 'btn-delete btn btn-xs btn-primary';
        //Icon for the Show Button
        $showButtonIcon = 'fa fa-eye';
        //text for the Show button
        $showButtonText  = '';
        $showButtonTooltopPostion = 'top';
        // End Show Button Arguments
        //Start Arguments for DropDown Buttons
        $dropDownButtonName = 'Actions';
        //End Arguments for DropDown Buttons




        $showButton = '';
        $showButton .='
            <a href="'.$fullUrl.'/'.$id.'"class="'.$showButtonClass.'"data-toggle="tooltip"data-placement="'.$showButtonTooltopPostion.'"title="'.$showFunctionTitle.'-'.$titleValue.'">
                <i class="'.$showButtonIcon.'"></i> '.$showButtonText.'
            </a>
        ';

        $editButton ='';
        $editButton .='
                <a href="'.$urlWithId.'/edit'.'"class="'.$editButtonClass.'"data-toggle="tooltip"data-placement="'.$editButtonTooltopPostion.'" title="'.$editFunctionTitle.'-'.$titleValue.'">
                    <i class="'.$editButtonIcon.'"></i> '.$editButtonText.'
                </a>
            ';


        $deleteButton='';
        $deleteButton .='
                <form id="form-delete-row' . $id . '"  method="'.$postMethod.'" action="'.$urlWithId.'" accept-charset="'.$charset.'"style="display: inline" onSubmit="return confirm(&quot;'.$deleteConfirmationDialog.'&quot;)">
                    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
                    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="'.$token.'">
                    <input name="_id" type="hidden" value="'.$id.'">
                    <button type="submit"class="'.$deleteButtonClass.'"data-toggle="tooltip"data-placement="'.$deleteButtonTooltopPostion.'" title="'.$deleteFunctionTitle.'-'.$titleValue.'">
                        <i class="'.$deleteButtonIcon.'"></i>'.$deleteButtonText.'
                    </button>
                </form>
            ';


    // $deleteButton = "<a href='index.php?page=de_activate_organization&action_id=$id' onClick=\"return confirm('Are you Sure to De Activate?')\"><span class='label label-success'>" ."Test" . "</span></a>";



        $actionButtons = '';

        foreach ($buttonActions as $buttonAction)
        {
            if ($buttonAction == 'show')
            {
                $actionButtons .= $showButton;
            }
            if ($buttonAction == 'edit')
            {
                $actionButtons .= $editButton;
            }
            if ($buttonAction == 'delete')
            {
                $actionButtons .= $deleteButton;
            }
        }
        if (empty($buttonOptions))
        {
            return  $actionButtons;
        }
        elseif (!empty($buttonOptions))
        {
            if ($buttonOptions == 'group')
            {

                $buttonGroup = '<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="">
                '.$actionButtons.'
                </div>';
                return $buttonGroup;
            }elseif($buttonOptions == 'dropdown')
            {
                $dropDownButton  =
                    '<div class="dropdown">
                      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        '.$dropDownButtonName.'
                      </button>
                      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                      '.$actionButtons.'
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    ';
                    return $dropDownButton;
            }else
            {
                return  'only <code>group</code> and <code>dropdown</code> is Available ';
            }

        }
    }
```

ok thats it now open your list file it may be `index.blade.php`

```
 @foreach($offers->Images as $image)
         <tr>
            <td><img src="{{ url('storage/photo/'.$image->imageUnsb) }}" width="100px" height="100px"></td>
            <td>{!!App\Offer::tableActionButtons(url()->full(),$image->id,$image->id,['show','edit','delete'])!!}</td>
            @endforeach
```

if you need icon

```
dont forgot to add fontawesome css
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This one:

```
@foreach($users as $key => $user)
  {!! Form::open(['route' => ['offers', $user->id],'method' => 'POST','style' => 'display:inline-block'])!!}

    {{ Form::submit(($user->status == 1) ? 'Ban User' : 'Activate User', ["class"=> "btn btn-red confirm-action"]) }}

  {!! Form::close() !!}
@endforeach
```